# Create multiple nodes having the same name with sub nodes

Tags: python, xml, celementtree

I have a text file, I parsed it with python using `xml.etree.cElementTree` library. 
In the input I have a paragraph `<p>` containing sentences `<s>`, each sentence have words `<w>`, here is the text file what it looks like:

```
This
is
my
first
sentence.
This
is
my
second
sentence.
```

In the output I would like to have the following xml file:

```xml
<p>
   <s>
      <w>this</w>
      <w>is</w>
      <w>my</w>
      <w>first</w>
      <w>sentence</w>
      <pc>.</pc>
   </s>
   <s>
      <w>this</w>
      <w>is</w>
      <w>my</w>
      <w>second</w>
      <w>sentence</w>
      <pc>.</pc>
   </s>
</p>
```

I wrote the following python code that give me the paragraph tag and the word tag, and I don't know how to implement the case to have multiple `<s>` tag. A sentence start with capital letter and end with a dot. 
My python code:

```py
source_file = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in source_file:
    # catch ponctuation : . and , and ! and ? and ()
    if re.match("(\(|\)|\.|\,|\!)", str(line)):
        ET.SubElement(p, "pc").text = line
    else:
        ET.SubElement(p, "w").text = line

tree.write("my_file.xml", encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

following xml output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
   <w>this</w>
   <w>is</w>
   <w>my</w>
   <w>first</w>
   <w>sentence</w>
   <pc>.</pc>
   <w>this</w>
   <w>is</w>
   <w>my</w>
   <w>second</w>
   <w>sentence</w>
   <pc>.</pc>
</p>
```

The problem I am facing is that I can't create a new `<s>` tag for every new sentence, is there a way to do that with the xml library using python ?

Comment: how do you identify new sentence ? each line is a new sentence or each period (dot) is ?
You could use something like below,
s = ET.Element('s') 
and then
w = ET.SubElement(s, 'w')

Comment: a new sentence is defined as the first word starting with capital letter, and ending with a `<pc>` tag containing a (dot). I tried what you said before but when looping through each line how can I use the same `s = ET.Element('s')` created before for the second sentence !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need a logic to identify new sentence. Ignoring the obvious parts, something like below should do,

```
import os
eos = False
s = ET.SubElement(p, 's')
for line in source_file:
    line = str(line).rstrip(os.linesep) #to remove new line char at the end of each line
    # catch ponctuation : . and , and ! and ? and ()
    if re.match("(\(|\)|\.|\,|\!)", line):   #don't think this matches 'sentence.', you will need to verify
        ET.SubElement(s, "pc").text = line
        eos = True
    else:
        if eos and line.strip() and line[0].isupper():
            s = ET.SubElement(p, 's')
        eos = False
        ET.SubElement(s, "w").text = line
```

Also, your regex might need a fix

Comment: Thanks man that's what I was missing from the puzzle, I tried adding flag like you did to control the end of sentence and ended with spaghetti code lol. After modifying my code and applying your implementation worked like a charm ! Thanks again.